# Une nuance entre « pousser/inciter/conduire/amener qqn à faire »

Tags: sens

> Qu'est-ce qui t’a **poussé** à acheter cette maison ?
>
> Qu'est-ce qui t’a **incité** à acheter cette maison ?
>
> Qu'est-ce qui t’a **conduit** à acheter cette maison ?
>
> Qu'est-ce qui t’a **amené** à acheter cette maison ?

Je m’interroge sur la nuance de sens entre les quatre, ainsi que sur le registre auquel chacun d’eux appartient.

Comment: I don’t have an answer to either of your interesting questions, but I would suggest that you could perhaps get a more comprehensive response covering the full spectrum of the nuances if your example sentences were not so heavily loaded toward the negative side of neutral.  Maybe replacing “une maison au milieu de nulle part” with “cette maison” would help in this respect.  Otherwise, I interpret all four as they are now written as being more formal (but not necessarily more polite) ways of saying: “Quelle idée d'acheter une maison dans ce bled!?!”

Comment: @PapaPoule A good point you've raised there, indeed. In English, "**encourage** someone to do" is used in a positive sense, while "**lead** someone to do" is used neutrally, whereas "**incite** someone to do" is reserved for a negative context. I posted this question, wondering if the same positive/neutral/negative connotations exist among these four verbs.

Comment: Yes it is a good question. .... I was actually suggesting to use only "cette maison" (and completely omit "au milieu de nulle part") and not just replace "une" with "cette" in order not to skew the example sentences at all toward the negative. Perhaps the nuances in the 4 verbs, if any, should be permitted to do the skewing without help from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @PapaPoule Besides the three already mentioned, there are also "**drive** someone to do" and "**possess** someone to do". These five (albeit similar) do not sound the same to English speakers, each having a particular flavour. So French speakes might likewise detect some nuances among these four verbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **"poussé"** indique une raison précise qui était le moteur de la motivation.

  "Qu'est-ce qui t’a poussé à acheter cette maison ?" sous-entend que la décision d'acheter a été renforcée par une raison précise.

  On peut parfois entendre une inflexion de doute avec cette expression. Comme si celui qui pose la question n'était pas sûr de comprendre pourquoi la personne a acheté cette maison.
- **"incité"** est équivalent mais est plus neutre que "poussé". Il n'y a aucun sous-entendu, on demande simplement quelle est la raison de cet achat, mais on continue de penser qu'il y a une raison précise.
- **"conduit"** est comme "incité" mais évoque la possibilité d'un cheminement logique et suppose une idée de direction. Les deux termes sont ici équivalents, mais "conduit" évoque l'idée d'une décision qui s'est construite dans le déroulement du temps.
- **"amené"** est identique à "conduit" dans ce contexte.

Ces quatre expressions sont des variations de "Pour quelle raison as-tu acheté cette maison ?" mais incluent une nuance d'incertitude, de doute. En utilisant ces expressions, on ne demande pas simplement pourquoi, on demande pourquoi parce qu'on est un peu étonné.

Comment: Je valide les nuances exposées ici.

Answer (score 2):

Je classerais les quatres verbes, du plus au moins formal, comme ceci :
*incité* > *conduit* = *amené* > *poussé*

Bien que même *poussé* reste tout à fait acceptable.

Comme l'a dit Papa Poule, il reste encore beaucoup de marge pour aller dans des registres plus formal ou soutenu.